# How do I make transition without affecting submit button on-click animation?

Tags: html, css, button, input

I've made a button transition on hover which is fine, but when I click on the submit button now its default animation is changed to transition specified and the click feel is too slow. How do I avoid transition animation for button on-click?

- another sub-question is: How can I change the border color of input email textbox along with button hover?

nother

```css
.novice_btn {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background: #99745c;
  width: 80px;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #99745c;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  
  /*transition*/
  -webkit-transition: all ease 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all ease 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all ease 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: all ease 0.5s;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
}

.novice_btn:hover {
  background: #4B301F;
  border-color: #4B301F;
}

.novice_input {
 font-family: 'Raleway';
 font-size: 11px;
 color: #000000;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 400px;
 height: 10px;
 outline:none; 
 border: 1px solid;
 border-color: #99745c;
 margin-top: 40px; 
}

/* BORDER TEXTBOX */

.novice_btn:hover  .novice_input{
 border-color: #4B301F;
}
```

```html
<table height="30" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="novice_input" placeholder="Email" type="text"></input>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="novice_btn" value="Send" type="submit"></input>
    </td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have updated my answer, hope it helps a little more

Comment: And if this answers your question please mark it as an answer so other community members can see that it is an answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the HTML code shown you cannot select the text input because it cannot be accessed by any CSS selectors. However, this can be done through JavaScript.

Some jQuery:

```
$('.novice_button').mouseover(function () {
   $('.novice_input').css({'border-color': 'black'});
});
// and some code for reset styling
```

And for the button issue try:

```
.novice_button:active {
   transition: 0s;
   background-color: #4B301F;
}
```

If this is not what you are looking for, please comment back and I am happy to help.